# how i can use dynamic div id in click function of jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none;" class="abcd">
     <p>Black</p>
 </div>
  <div id="div2" style="display:none;"  class="abcd">
    <p>Red</p>

 </div>
  <div id="div3" style="display:none;" class="abcd">
   <p>Blue</p>
 </div>

<input type="button" value="Black" id="black" class="btn" 
onClick="showDiv('div1')"/>

<input type="button" value="Red" id="red" class="btn" 
onClick="showDiv('div2')"/>

<input type="button" value="Blue" id="blue" class="btn" 
onClick="showDiv('div3')"/>

function showDiv(divId){

$('.abcd').hide();
$('#'+divId).show();

}
```

I am using the above code in javascript to show hide divs when corresponding button is     clicked and remaining divs need to hide.I am passing the div id from javascript function.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){ 

});
```

Here how i can pass those divid dynamically in jQuery .click event.Thanks in advance....

Comment: If you're using `jQuery` there's no reason to have any inline js.

Comment: to avoid that only i need solution

Comment: How button and div are related in your example?

Comment: when i click on first button ineed to show first div .....etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would be a bit of a cleaner method, without onclick:

```
<input data-id="div1" type="button" value="Black" id="black" class="btn" />

<input data-id="div2" type="button" value="Red" id="red" class="btn" />

<input data-id="div3" type="button" value="Blue" id="blue" class="btn"/>

$('.btn').click(function(){
   $('#'+$(this).data('id')).toggle(); 
});
```

this way you could show/toggle any element if you insert its id into the `data-id` attribute of the button.

Comment: Can you use `data` method to manipulate the DOM, or do you need to use `attr('data-id')` ?

Comment: data('id') or  attr('data-id')

Comment: @Andy it is not  working for me.I sit not hiding the previous divs

Comment: Thanks i updated the code here http://jsfiddle.net/BYLKU/1/ it is working for me.

Comment: @c--misura the `data()` function doesn't manipulate the DOM. It only reads and changes the internal data object. The value of the `data-something` attribute will be stored inside the data object with the name converted to camel case. For example `data-some-stuff` can be read with .data('someStuff')

Comment: @PSR Yes, only attributes starting with data- will be stored in the data object. but you could theoretically save arbitrary attributes and only work with those. but i'd not recommend it. usually the data-attribute is only used to set an initial value and then you'd only work with the data object

Answer (score 3):

Since you give your input class `btn`, you need to use `.` instead of `#` for reference. Then you can do like this to show the div according to the button clicked:

```
$('.btn').click(function(i) {
    var index = $(this).index('input') + 1;
    $('#div' + index).show().siblings('div').hide();
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/H9pyk/1/)**

Comment: +1 Thanks for help .you solution is alos working .But i can accept only one answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.abcd').not(':contains('+$(this).val()+')').hide();
    $('.abcd:contains('+$(this).val()+')').show();
});
```

This way you won't need the `onClick` attribute on your `<button>` elements as you'll look based on the fact that your `<div>` elements have a `<p>` with a text equal to the value of the clicked button...

[**Jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/kpL22/)

Comment: +1 Thanks for help .you solution is alos working .But i can accept only one answer.